# Android Studio: Notification not showing even though it is called

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have an app that I want to send me a notification every day at 6 am (midnight), I am working with the WorkManager for that after trying Alarms. I currently have a class extending Worker as follows:

```java
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {
    Context context;

    public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, 0);

        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle("App Title")
                .setContentText("Some Text...")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) HomePage.getHomePage().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

it is called by this snippet of code that is inside my onCreate() function of my Activity

```java
WorkRequest notificationRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(notificationRequest);
```

the doWork() method is called but no notification is shown. Any help would be apreciated.

- This code "should" only show the notification upon loading the Activity, any ideas on how I can make it repeat every day? (preferably with WorkManager too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in Android 26, Notifications must be passed a propper notification Channel.

> Caution: If you target Android 8.0 (API level 26) and post a
> notification without specifying a notification channel, the
> notification does not appear and the system logs an error.

Please see the following [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) for information.

You can use the following code to build the channel, where CHANNEL_ID is a string of your choosing

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = ctx.getString(R.string.my_channel_name);
            String description = ctx.getString(R.string.my_channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            //Register Channel
            NotificationManager notificationManager = ctx.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }
    }
```

Then when initializing your Notification Builder, pass an additional parameter for the Channel ID

```
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
```

You will usually also want to pass a priority to your builder as follows, to support Android 25 and lower

```
notification.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: After Messing around with it, this worked great! However: I had to put my Notification.Builder in an if statement body that checked for the version as the constructor with Channel_ID is not supported below 26. The else body contains the setPriority method as that one is deprecated after 26.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. You are correct with the API check, I didn't catch that as I generally use NotificationCompat.builder, which provides backwards compatibility, and allows you to make those calls without breaking anything